# Elevation not working on BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-elevation, bottomnavigationview

The elevation on my BottomNavigationView isn't woking, when I start my app all the other UI components get their specific elevation but the BottomNavigationView.

Here's the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do?

Note: no color is transparent.

Comment: add  `android:background` attribute to BottomNavigationView and see if it works

Comment: still no change

Comment: having the same problem. Did you find the solution? @Ale4303

Comment: no, not yet. Still searching :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use the namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and use the  `app:elevation = "8dp"` instead of `android:elevation="8dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Shadow is drawn downwards (from the bottom of the view), you can see that `android:elevation="8dp"` is applied if you try to show `Snackbar`, you won't be able to see it.

If you want to add shadow that will be shown from the top of the `BottomNavigationView` you need to draw it [manually](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iosched/+/HEAD/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DrawShadowFrameLayout.java).